# Unauthorized firewall rules on SSH bastion servers

Tags: ssh, iptables

Yesterday I found that a few firewall rules (iptables on Ubuntu 20.04 OS) have been added to an SSH bastion server that allow SSH access on a custom SSH port number. All IPs are from Vietnam.
AFAIK iptables rules can be added only by a user with root privileges, right? Does this means that my servers have been compromised?!

These SSH bastions are hardened and SSH port is not publicly available but only through Port Knocking system. Furthermore OS are fully up to date and Livepatch is installed so as to install security patches as soon as they are released.
I'm now looking into system logs and the only thing I've found so far is these lines in auth.log file:

```
Oct 28 19:31:01 staging sshd[5707]: error: kex_exchange_identification: banner line contains invalid characters
Oct 28 19:31:01 staging sshd[5707]: banner exchange: Connection from 103.167.XX.XXX port 57061: invalid format
```

Any idea how come these firewall rules have been added by unauthorized IPs?!

Comment: Do you have auditing enabled on your machine? If so, you should be able to see when and possibly who added these firewall rules. Firewall rules can indeed only be modified with root privileges.

Comment: Hi @Jeroen
You mean auditd daemon? Unfortunately no, is not enabled...
Any other way to investigate this?

Comment: How is the bastion host configured? Do you use configuration management tools (e.g. ansible, chef etc) or do you manually setup the box?

Comment: @RobertoJobet Yes, this is exactly what I was referring to. I'm thinking perhaps syslog but I am not sure if changes are actually logged.

Comment: @Spyros Servers are manually setup. Why? Could this be relevant?

Comment: In automated installations, servers generally are deployed based on certain requirements / policies where manual installations things tend to be forgotten (like auditd for example)

Comment: There's always the case that someone could have gained access to the computer of one of the people that usually configure the bastion host, pivoted in and made the changes. If this is the case you won't find anything suspicious in the logs of the bastion host because the changes are legit (from the bastion host's point of view). Same idea with using a configuration managemet tool; my point is that maybe you need to look elsewhere to see if there was actually an intrusion